# wordpress front-page.php not loading css correctly

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a blog for our site in Wordpress. I have index.php page which was used by the front page (www....somedomain.com). I have now created a blog page which uses index.php and and a front page which uses front-page.php. I have copied contents on the index.php folder to front-page.php. After I do that, the blog page works fine ([www.----domainname.com/blog](http://www.----domainname.com/blog)) where as the home page (www......domainname.com) is having issues loading css.

Any particular reason for such behaviours.

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Basit

Comment: There is no way your WordPress site uses html file.

Comment: sorry, it was supposed to be index.php page